# java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using retrofit and okhttp to make a server call. But sometimes I get an error which crashes with the following log.(I am using a GET call):

Log:

```
: java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream
  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream$ChunkedSource.read(Http1xStream.java:442)
at okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:371)
at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
 at retrofit.Utils.streamToBytes(Utils.java:43)
 at retrofit.Utils.readBodyToBytesIfNecessary(Utils.java:81)
  at retrofit.RestAdapter.logAndReplaceResponse(RestAdapter.java:483)
at retrofit.RestAdapter.access$500(RestAdapter.java:107)
at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:338)
at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
 at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Code:

```
 final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
.setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
          .setEndpoint(URL).build();                                     
        myapi myapi_rest = restAdapter.create(myapi.class);
        myapi_rest.my_call(
                sno,
                new Callback<Response>() {

                    @Override
                    public void success(Response result, Response response) {


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                        // Log.i("Failure", "Error"+error.getMessage());

                    }
                });
```

Comment: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2738